# gettext() always return empty in Protractor

Tags: typescript, selenium, protractor

I have an issues getting the text from an element in protractor.

This is what I tried:

```
passwordError:ElementFinder = element(by.xpath("//*[@id='error-message']"));

let errorMessage:string = await this.passwordError.getText();

console.log("The error is: "+ errorMessage );
```

I'm expecting `Wrong email or password` text. But the `gettext()` method is always returning an empty string.

```
<body class="bg">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0px;">
    <nav class="navbar" style="background:#020202;">
      <a class="navbar-brand ml-2" href="#"><img src="https://er-au-images.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/cc/logowhite.svg" style="height:48px;" /></a>
    </nav>
    <section class="">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="align-self-center" style="position:absolute;left:25%;top:25%;width:50%;background:#ffffff;margin:0px;padding:0px;">
            <div class="col-6" style="float:left;margin:0px;padding:0px;">
              <div class="mainback"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6" style="float:left;margin:0px;padding:5%;padding-top:10%;">
              <form onsubmit="return false;" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:40px;">
                  <h2>Centre Login</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:2px;">
                 <label for="email">User Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="" class="form-control input-nofocus">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:2px;">
                  <label for="password">Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="" class="form-control input-nofocus">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="width:100%;">
                  <div class="text-right" style="clear:left;"><a style="color:#ffd101;">Forgot your login?</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
                  <button type="submit" id="btn-login" class="btn btn-ever">LOGIN</button>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  **<div id="error-message" class="alert alert-danger">Wrong email or password.</div>**
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works Binoj Mathew. Refer the code and terminal output.

[image]

Comment: Yes Bharath,The issue was because of delay in updating the DOM